# Filter a list from a hyperlink?

Tags: list, development, web-part, visual-studio

I currently have a webpart written in C# that displays the latest news headlines from a SharePoint list.

What I would like to do from that webpart is that when an item is clicked it returns the full article in new Full page view queried from the news list. I don't mind using C# to code another webpart to do this, but my question is how do I query the list using the hyperlink as the query source? Any code examples would be appreciated!.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your existing webpart and add logic to read the list item id. Then you can form the URL something like

```
 http://webapplication/sites/lists/newslist.aspx?ListItemID=57
```

In the above 57 is the list item id of that particular news.

Now edit the `newlist.aspx` page. Add a webpart which can read the News List where Id the id value present in the query string.